# android maps custom info window, how to to return the cutom info window after getting data from firestore?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get info from firestore on user click on a marker and show it in the custom info window, the problem is I have to click multiple times before I get the updated values.
What would be the best way to do this?

this is the code I have:

```
public class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    private final View mWindow;
    private Context mContext;
    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private String selectedStation;
    private long safeVotes;
    private long unsafeVotes;

    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(Context mContext) {
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        this.mContext = mContext;
        mWindow = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
    }

    private void renderWindowText(final Marker marker, final View view) {
        db.collection("game1").document("position").collection("collection").whereEqualTo("location", marker.getPosition())
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            selectedStation = document.getId();
                            DocumentReference currentStationRef = db.collection("game1").document("position").collection("1").document(selectedStation);
                            currentStationRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                    long safeVotes = 0;
                                    long unsafeVotes = 0;
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                        if (document.exists()) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
//                                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "" + document.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            Map<String, Object> stationHashmap = document.getData();
                                            safeVotes = (long) stationHashmap.get("safe votes");
                                            CustomInfoWindowAdapter.this.safeVotes = safeVotes;
                                            unsafeVotes = (long) stationHashmap.get("unsafe votes");
                                            CustomInfoWindowAdapter.this.unsafeVotes = unsafeVotes;
//                                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "safe: " + safeVotes + "; unsafe votes: " + unsafeVotes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            //putting info in the custom info window
                                            String title = marker.getTitle();
                                            TextView titleTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.station_name);
                                            titleTextView.setText(title);
                                            TextView safeVotesTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.safe_votes);
                                            safeVotesTextView.setText("SafeVotes: " + safeVotes);
                                            TextView unsafeVotesTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.unsafe_votes);
                                            unsafeVotesTextView.setText("Unsafe Votes: " + unsafeVotes);

                                            String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
                                        } else {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }

//                        Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "SELECTED: " + selectedStation, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        selectedStationTextView.setText(selectedStation);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        renderWindowText(marker, mWindow);

        return mWindow;//before returning this I want renderWindowText(marker, mWindow); to complete fetching data
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        renderWindowText(marker, mWindow);
        return mWindow;
    }
}
```

I think it's possible to add a delay before returning the mWindow, but it doesn't seem like the best option. Can I return the view from inside the OnCompleteListener?

Comment: Which view would you like to return?

Comment: mWindow like:

public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return renderWindowText(marker, mWindow);
    }         if renderWindowText had a return type of View for example

Comment: You should wait for the data. Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** out.